# Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, boolean

Hello I'm workig in an angular project with php. But I have this error "Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'" in this line "return this.isLogin(routeurl);". How can I solve it please?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree, CanActivate, Router } from 
'@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate {
constructor(private dataService: ApiService,private router: Router ) {}
canActivate(
route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
const routeurl: string = state.url;
return this.isLogin(routeurl);
}

isLogin(routeurl: string) {
if (this.dataService.isLoggedIn()) {
return true;
}

this.dataService.redirectUrl = routeurl;
this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: { returnUrl: routeurl }} );
}
}
```

I have also this error "(method) AuthguardGuard.isLogin(routeurl: string): true | undefined
Not all code paths return a value." in this line "isLogin(routeurl: string) "
thanks in advance

Comment: IsLogin does not return any value if the user is not logged in.
You can just return the result from the dataService directly.
`return this.dataService.isLoggedIn()`

That method also does not make use of the routeurl parameter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript complains that you return a value of type `boolean | undefined` when it expects it to be just `boolean`.

Assuming the return type of `this.isLogin(routeurl)` is `boolean | undefined` you could simply return a default value when it actually is `ùndefined`.

```
return this.isLogin(routeurl) ?? false;
```

For your second problem you simply have to return something at the end of the method:

```
isLogin(routeurl: string) {
if (this.dataService.isLoggedIn()) {
return true;
}

this.dataService.redirectUrl = routeurl;
this.router.navigate(['/login'], {queryParams: { returnUrl: routeurl }} );
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined is diff from the boolean. If your function can return undefined you need to explicit this like:

```
canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | undefined {
  const routeurl: string = state.url;
  return this.isLogin(routeurl);
}
```